# How can I submit a URL to Google's search engine without having a Google account?

Tags: google-search, link-submission

How can I notify Google's search engine of the existence of a website without opening an account with that company?

Comment: You don't even need to submit URLs to Google.  Google will find and index pages shortly after they get just one link from something else that is already indexed.

Comment: Creating a Google account isn't hard.   You could even have one that is only used just for submitting URLs.   What is the use case of submitting a URL without a Google account?

Comment: There is a benefit in the company mentioning one's website to net users who make use of its websearch engine, as many do, and there are disadvantages in allowing it to know one's phone number and birthdate and to install malware on one's computers.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible; a Google account is required to submit URLs. However, you shouldn't need to manually submit URLS as Google should crawl your website automatically in a timely manner.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in Google’s [Introduction to Indexing](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-indexing), you don’t have to submit your URLs in order to get them crawled. If you can get links to your new pages from pages already indexed, Google’s crawlers will find the new URLs the next time they crawl the indexed pages again.

There might be an alternative that can be used without Google account: [pinging Google with the URL to your sitemap](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/submit-URLs):

> Ping Google specifically with the location of the sitemap: (`http://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=URL/of/file`)

However, this is documented in a context for notifying Google about changes to your structured data, and it’s not mentioned in the section [Make your sitemap available to Google (Submit your sitemap to Google)](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=4581190#addsitemap) on a different page, so it’s not clear if Google will accept *new* sitemaps this way.

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago Google Publish an open submission at Google SERP. You can read for more https://searchengineland.com/submit-urls-google-googles-search-results-272871

And there is some website through them you can submit your site without opening an account.

You can share your content on different Social Media like (G+, FB, Twitter etc.) for quick index your page or website.

Comment: The box at the top of SERP only shows if you’re logged in.

Comment: I agree. I think it's best if you do have a Google account. It's better seeing how Google sees your site.

Answer (score 0):

Google used to claim that they crawled any page linked from Google+ within 24 hours. Hard to know if that's totally true or if it's *still* true. But it's quick and easy, so I do it routinely as a "just in case".

Comment: As the user doesn't want to open a Google account, I don't see how Google+ is a valid solution.

Comment: You can post the link from any Google+ account, not just your client's. The user only comments that they don't want to open "an account with that company".

I have assumed "that company" means the client, not Google. If I am wrong there, then yes my answer isn't really helpful. But it seems an odd request and a half-hearted boycott..?

Comment: [As Google+ dies](https://www.engadget.com/2018/10/08/google-shutting-down-google-plus/), this answer dies too. RIP.